# Arrange numbers to form the biggest interger , Problem in understanding the comparator

Tags: java, comparator

Below is the code from GFG to generate biggest number from a given set of integers.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class GFG { 


    static void printLargest(Vector<String> arr){ 
    
        Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>(){ 

        @Override
        public int compare(String X, String Y) { 
        
    
        String XY=X + Y; 
        
        String YX=Y + X; 
        
        return XY.compareTo(YX) > 0 ? -1:1; 
    } 
    }); 
        
    Iterator it = arr.iterator(); 

    while(it.hasNext()) 
        System.out.print(it.next()); 
    
    } 
    
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        
        Vector<String> arr; 
        arr = new Vector<>(); 
        arr.add("54"); 
        arr.add("546"); 
        arr.add("548"); 
        arr.add("60");
        printLargest(arr); 
    } 
}
```

Above code is basically sorting the vector values using the comparator,
But I am unable to understand this portion. Can someone please explain the comparator logic?

```
return XY.compareTo(YX) > 0 ? -1:1; 
    } 
    }); 
        
    Iterator it = arr.iterator(); 

    while(it.hasNext()) 
        System.out.print(it.next()); 
    
    }
```

Comment: Those are not integers, those are strings. And I doubt that this sorting algorithm actually works: the `compare` method is not symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

In the comparator, we are trying to compare the final string which will be generated by arranging X and Y.

for eg: If X is "546" and Y is "54", then X + Y will be "54654" and Y+X will be "54546" and Y+X > X+Y.

**Algorithm Explained**

Assumption: Assuming that the numbers are distinct to simplify the problem.

Let's use bubble sort to understand the logic behind the comparator. In bubble sort we keep comparing two consecutive elements till the point that all the elements are in order.

Let the array to be sorted be `s1, s2, s3, s4........sn`

If we have two consecutive elements X and Y in the array such that YX > XY
the swapping of those two elements creates a bigger element.

```
 s1 + s2 + .... + X + Y  + ..sn  <  s1 + s2 + ..... Y + X + .. sn
```

Thus in bubble sort, we try comparing and swapping until no such pairs are left where YX > XY and X have a less index in the array then Y.

Whether these operations will result in the biggest integer which can be formed by those given ints?

Assume that this is not the case i.e the biggest integer(A) differs from our algorithm, then we have will have a different permutation of elements in the biggest integer and there will be an X, Y where the index of X is less than that to Y and YX > XY.

Number A can be represented as

```
 A = s1 + s2 + ..... X + Y......sn
```

But by changing the position of Y and X we can create a bigger element than A. Thus A is not the biggest element. Hence we have proved by contradiction, that the algorithm produces the biggest integer.